# Retrieve nested data using Baqend - undefined

Tags: ionic3, baqend

I am building an app using ionic 3 and Baqend for BaaS.

If I have the following data:

```
product :{
   id: xxx,
   item: {
      name: "Name",
      description: "product details.."
   }  
}
```

How do I retrieve the value in 'item.name'?

I tried the following but gives me 'undefined'. It works if I do `product.id` but not the case for nested data.

```
import { baqend } from "baqend";

...

db: baqend;

...

this.db.Products.find().resultList(function(results) {
   results.forEach(function(product) {
      console.log(product.item.name);
   });
});
```

I am following the Baqend guide:
https://www.baqend.com/guide/topics/queries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases this happens, if you didn't define the item and name property in the schema properly. 
To actually nest data in a baqend model you should define the property as an [embedded property](https://www.baqend.com/guide/topics/schema/#embedded-objects) (shown in the screenshot below) or as an untyped JsonObject.

Your defined schema of Products should look similar to the following:

[image: Products schema]

Hope that helps so far.

Comment: I see. I was actually using type 'List' for item. Do I need to declare 'ProductItem' somewhere first?